# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass in app/views/articles/new.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and trying to add validation to text field. My class:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }

    def new
      @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

      if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

end
```

My new.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

And when I try to add new article I open http://localhost:3000/articles/new but instead of the form I see error `undefined method errors' for nil:NilClass` because of the error in this line `<% if @article.errors.any? %>`

What am I missing here. Looks like `@article` is being validated before created? How can I fix it?

Comment: Instead of `form_for :article, url: articles_path` you can do `form_for @article`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The code is as-written in the Rails Guides, it's just copy-pasted.

Comment: It looks like that you have copy pasted the code in wrong place, I dont think there is an issue with guide. even right before this code it says "Open the `app/models/article.rb` file and edit it:"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your model and controller are all meshed together into one class. That cannot work.

You need **two** classes:

- A model called `Article` which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`
- A controller called `ArticlesController` which inherits from `ApplicationController`

The code you've posted is the model, but the actions you've added (`new` and `create`) need to go in the **controller**.

The guide you're following says (note the file names):

> Rails includes methods to help you validate the data that you send to models. Open the **app/models/article.rb** file and edit it:
>
> ```
> class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
>     validates :title, presence: true,
>              length: { minimum: 5 }
> end
> ```

And the below that,

> ... to do this, change the new and create actions inside **app/controllers/articles_controller.rb** to these:
>
> ```
> def new
>   @article = Article.new
> end
>
> def create
>   @article = Article.new(article_params)
>
>   # ...
> ```

Comment: Beat me to it - I was staring at the model in disbelief and since I'm so new at rails I wanted to check my own code before answering the same lol

Comment: What a silly mistake! I used model class instead of controller. Oh my gosh. Of course, I moved code to the right place and now it's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

validate part should reside in Modal which is Article < ActiveRecord::Base. and rest of your code should be Article controller

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your validation in your model as :

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

And your actions should be in controller as :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
       redirect_to @article
    else
       render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
   def article_params
     params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
   end


end
```

And at last change you form as:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

under the new.html.erb file, replace the following line:

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
```

with this:

```
<% if form.object.errors.any? %>
```